# Understanding the order of task completion and cancellation

Tags: .net, asynchronous, async-await, task, cancellation

I'm trying to untangle this async behavior.  Given this code:

```
static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    var cts = new CancellationTokenSource(4000);

    try
    {
        await DoOperationAsync(cts.Token);
    }
    catch (OperationCanceledException)
    {
        Console.WriteLine
            ($"Operation canceled prematurely at {DateTime.Now}");
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Press any key...");
    Console.ReadKey(true);
}

static async Task DoOperationAsync
    (CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var t1 = Method("one", 5000, cancellationToken);
    var t2 = Method("two", 5000, cancellationToken);
    var first = await Task.WhenAny(t1, t2);

    Console.WriteLine
        ($"Finished first: {(first == t2 ? "two" : "one")}, {first.Status}");

    var result = await first;
}

static async Task<string> Method
    (string name, int delayMs, 
    CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Started method {name} at {DateTime.Now}");
    await Task.Delay(delayMs, cancellationToken);
    Console.WriteLine($"Finished method {name} at {DateTime.Now}");
    return name;
}
```

Why does "two" get canceled and "complete" first even though it started second, and then why does "one" never fault?

Here is the output:

```
Started method one at 2022-09-01 09:02:43
Started method two at 2022-09-01 09:02:43
Finished first: two, Canceled
Operation canceled prematurely at 2022-09-01 09:02:47
Press any key...
Finished method one at 2022-09-01 09:02:48
```

Comment: add a `await Task.Delay(2000);` before the `Console.ReadKey(true);` and you will see the one task does not output the finished message. `Console.ReadKey` seems to block the `CancellationToken´ cancel notification of the task. Maybe Stephen Cleary has some more technical backgrounds at hand

Answer (score 3):

It's actually because of this line:

```
Console.ReadKey(true);
```

Task completion is a bit tricky because it's *synchronous*. This is fine as long as you don't block in asynchronous code (which the `ReadKey` does). I explain more fully [on my blog](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/12/dont-block-in-asynchronous-code.html). When I first came across this behavior, I reported it as a bug since it was so unexpected.

There are two synchronous behaviors that cause this in this example:

1. `await` continues its asynchronous method synchronously (if possible).
2. `CancellationToken` [invokes its registered callbacks synchronously](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/threading/cancellation-in-managed-threads?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5000058#listening-by-registering-a-callback) (always).

Both of those don't cause any problems *unless* you're doing blocking in an asynchronous method (or in a `CancellationToken` callback).

So, to step through what's happening in your example:

1. Both `one` and `two` are started, and they both call `Task.Delay`, which registers a callback with the `CancellationToken`.
2. When the code reaches the `WhenAny`, it returns an incomplete task, which causes `Main` to return an incomplete task. ([See my blog for `await` details](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html)).
3. Some time later, the cancellation token will fire. When this happens, it invokes all its callbacks one at a time, *synchronously*. "Which callback is invoked first" is an implementation detail - it may change with a future .NET version and shouldn't be relied upon. The observed behavior with today's BCL is that `two` fires first, so let's assume that happens.
4. The continuation for `two` executes and completes its method. Note that this is run *within* the callback for the `CancellationToken`.
5. Since `two` completes its method, the `WhenAny` also completes, and the `DoOperationAsync` continues executing. Note that it's still within the `CancellationToken` callback.
6. `DoOperationAsync` observes the exception, completing the task it already returned to the `Main` method earlier.
7. This causes `Main`'s continuation to execute. Note that we're *still* in the first `CancellationToken` callback.
8. The code in `Main` catches the exception, writes out the message, and then *blocks waiting for user input*. It is blocking from within the `CancellationToken` callback.
9. Assume the user doesn't press the key within a subsecond after seeing `Main`'s message.
10. `one` now has sufficient time to complete. Its cancellation token is actually cancelled, but it hasn't been notified yet because it's second in the list of callbacks, and the callback in the first slot is blocked waiting for user input.

As a general rule, [don't block in `async` code](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/12/dont-block-in-asynchronous-code.html). If for some reason you need to, consider inserting an `await Task.Yield()` before the blocking code.

Side note: in Javascript, `await` is *always* asynchronous; continuations *never* run synchronously. Which IMO makes more sense and is less surprising, but it is also less efficient.

Comment: Question #1: on step 2 -- what happens in a console app when the main method returns?  There's no event loop like a WinForms app to keep doing stuff until the async operation signals completion to resume execution in the captured context, so what does the console app (having returned from the main method) do while the async operation is underway?

Comment: @rory.ap: Good question! To handle `async Main`, the runtime will just have the main Console thread block on the returned task.

Comment: Question #2: on step 3 you refer to callbacks on the cancellation token, but as I haven't registered any specific callbacks on the cancellation token (I'm thinking "ContinueWith" on the task or something?), do you mean just the "rest of the method"?  If so, then how does this continuation on a cancellation token differ from the normal, non-canceled continuation (i.e. when Task.Delay completes successfully)?

Comment: @rory.ap: I'm writing a blog series on cancellation, but haven't gotten to this topic yet. In summary, there's two ways for code to observe a cancellation token: periodic polling and registering a callback. Synchronous code generally uses polling and asynchronous code generally uses callbacks. In this case, the `Task.Delay` (an asynchronous method) uses a callback to cancel its timer when cancellation is requested.

Comment: Okay with this clarification, I fully understand.  Wow.  Thank you!

Comment: So, now thinking about mitigating this -- because if you're writing complex library code, some inappropriate blocking far up the call stack can affect the logic of your code.  In general, is there a best practice for ensuring proper cancelling of parallel tasks?  I'm guessing you're going to mention TPL Data Flow!

Comment: I think most library code doesn't have to protect against this. If users block in asynchronous code they're going to have problems with asynchronous BCL methods, not just your library.